# Always receive Error: parsererror in pushJsonData: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input [object Object] in my Script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I always receive the Parser error in pushJsonData and I don't know why.

I tested it first with just the user value and it works fine, but when I try to thrwo back mor than the user I recieve the error below:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input [object Object]`

My JavaScript code:

```
$('#Login').click(function() {
    var user = $("#user").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "src/ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { ACTION : "checkUser", USER: user},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data)  {
            var user = data.user;
            $('#testUser').text("Hallo " + user);
        },

        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + " in pushJsonData: " + errorThrown + " " + jqXHR);
        }
    });
});
```

My PHP code:

```
if($_POST['ACTION'] == "checkUser") {
    $checkUser      = $_POST['USER'];
    $sql            = $db->query("SELECT * FROM fm_user WHERE user = '".$checkUser."' LIMIT 1");
    $getUser        = $sql->fetch_assoc();

    $resultArray    = array(
                        "user" => $getUser['user'],
                        "isadmin" => $getUser['isadmin'],
                        "user_data" => $getUser['user_data']
                    );

    $result = json_encode($resultArray);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any output from the PHP code.

Comment: put echo $result; exit(): after $result assignment in PHP code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not outputting anything. But, rather than close this as off-topic due to a typo I wanted to point out some issues with your code, which is unsafe and inefficient. Always *always* use prepared statements, and there's no need to waste code putting array elements into an array. Something like this should work better:

```
<?php
if($_POST['ACTION'] == "checkUser") {
    $result = null;
    $checkUser = $_POST['USER'];
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT user, isadmin, user_data FROM fm_user WHERE user = ? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $checkUser);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $getUser = $result->fetch_assoc();

        $result = $getUser;
    }
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    echo json_encode($result);
    die();
}
```

Untested, and it's been a long time since I've used mysqli but it should work.

Comment: Hey thanks. Meanwhile i've handlet it by my self, but u're right it was an unsafe code so i use your version. FYI there was an ) to much afterbind_param :-)